Counting words in an unambiguous context-free grammar
Given an unambigious context-free grammar $G = (\Sigma, V, \mathcal R, S)$, is there a polynomial-time algorithm that calculates $|L(G)|$ (including the case where $|L(G)|$ is infinite)?

The rough idea I have is something along the lines of:

Find all rules of the form $A \to a$ where $a \in \Sigma^\star$.
Remove $A \to a$ and add new rules where $A$ appears in any productions in $\mathcal R$ by replacing them with $a$ (while also keeping the original).
If $A \to a$ was the only rule for $A$, remove any derivations containing $A$.
$\cdots$ some mystery steps $\cdots$
Then the grammar is of the form $S \to w_1 | \cdots | w_n$ where $n = |L(G)|$.

I can't see how to deal with detecting cycles, and also variables that are actually never used in any derivation. Thanks for any help!

I suggest you break this down into two subquestions: (1) given a context-free language, can you test whether it is finite or infinite, in polynomial time?  (2) given an unambiguous context-free grammar $G$ for a finite context-free language, can you compute $|L(G)|$ in polynomial time?
I believe the answer to (1) is yes; see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1891462/14578 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Emptiness_and_finiteness.
I believe the answer to (2) is also yes; see below.
The framework you sketch will not lead to a solution, as there are unambiguous context-free grammars that can generate a language with $2^n$ words using a grammar of size $O(n)$.  e.g., $S \to S_1$, $S_i \to aS_{i+1} | bS_{i+1}$, $S_n \to \varepsilon$.
However, the following algorithm,  due to Emil Jeřábek, does work.  My thanks to him for teaching me this.
First, remove all useless non-terminals from the grammar.
We will attempt to derive, for each non-terminal $A \in V$, the number $|L(A)|$, which counts the number of words accepted by $A$.  If we have a non-terminal $A$ with rules $A \to \alpha_1$, ..., $A \to \alpha_k$, then we find
$$|L(A)| = \sum_{i=1}^k \prod_{B \in \alpha_i} |L(B)|,$$
where the inner product ranges over all non-terminals contains in the right-hand side $\alpha_i$ of the $i$th rule.  Here we have used the fact that the grammar is unambiguous to use the sum rule for disjoint sets (for an unambiguous grammar, $L(\alpha_1),\dots,L(\alpha_k)$ are pairwise disjoint).
Now if there is a cycle in the dependency graph for these $|L(\cdot)|$ terms, then the language is infinite.  If there is no cycle, then we can compute the above $|L(\cdot)|$ values by traversing the dependency graph in topologically sorted order.  The whole procedure runs in essentially linear time, if we treat every addition and multiplication as taking $O(1)$ time.  Unfortunately the integers involved can be quite large, so the running time is not guaranteed to be polynomial, but it is polynomial in the size of the output.
Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17387686/781723, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4780758/14578.

What is the point of using polynomials rather than directly just the constants $A(1)$? You will not ever need any other value of $x$. Anyway, don’t think of it as a polynomial system to solve, but as an inductive definition of $A(1)$: the point is that if (after elimination of nonterminals that cannot appear in a derivation of any word) there is a cycle in the dependency graph on nonterminals, the language is infinite, hence you can assume the graph is a dag, and proceed by induction from the leaves to the root $S$. This does give a polynomial-time algorithm.

@EmilJeřábek, great point.  Thank you so much for that insight.  I have revised the answer accordingly.

I realized $|L(G)|$ might be doubly exponential in $|G|$, hence it may need an exponential number of bits to write down: e.g., consider the grammar $S_i\to aS_{i+1}bS_{i+1}$, $S_n\to ab\mid abab$. (The recursive expression for $|L(A)|$ implies that it can’t be worse than exponential in terms of bit-length, as the bit-length is at most multiplied by the number of nonterminals on the right-hand side at each step.) Thus, the procedure takes a linear number of arithmetic operations, but the overall runtime may be exponential; it is, however, polynomial in the bitsize of the output.

@EmilJeřábek, thank you for those excellent insights. I've updated my answer to incorporate that information.
